# CocoaPods install fails on Microsoft AppCenter for React Native projects

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

I am new to CocoaPods and I have been trying to build a RN project on MS AppCenter. My `Podfile` looks fairly simple:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'recommendapp' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  # See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]

  # React Native third party dependencies podspecs
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  # react-native-maps dependencies
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS

  # Pods for AppCenter
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.6.0'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.6.0'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.5.0'
  platform :ios, '9.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I trigger the build it fails with

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "yoga":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec`)

In Podfile:
    yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec`)

Due to the previous naïve CocoaPods resolver, you were using a pre-release version of `yoga`, without explicitly asking for a pre-release version, which now leads to a conflict. Please decide to either use that pre-release version by adding the version requirement to your Podfile (e.g. `pod 'yoga', '= 0.54.2.React'`) or revert to a stable version by running `pod update yoga`.

From what I can see, both yoga podspec definitions point to the same file but it still fails. I have carried out extensive searches on google and stackoverflow but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: I got it to work. Microsoft AppCenter used v1.3.1 of CocoaPods and I was using v1.5.0. So, I just had to regenerate the lockfile using the correct version.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you found your solution, I will leave mine for others who's having the same problem.

I got this issue when install react-native-maps.
It's caused due to dependency version conflict. I managed to solve it by using a quick-fix => I deleted the `Podfile.lock` in `/example/ios`, then `npm run build:ios`, which will generate the new file with correct version.

Answer (score -2):

Open the **Podfile** in your **platforms/ios/Podfile**.

Verify that the version is ios 9.0 (or the latest).

Save the file and then run `pod install` in the same directory using Terminal.

And then back to your cordova project and run:

```
cordova rm platform ios
cordova add platform ios
cordova build ios
cordova run ios
```

Thats it.